# can I use rosserial mbed library without using mbed os?

Tags: ros, rosserial, rosserial-client, rosserial-python

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi everyone,

I am using rosserial mbed with online compiler. It is fine for now but I want to use my STM32F767 nucleo board more efficiently. I am wondering that is it possible to use offline compiler and mbed rosserial library without using mbed os?

It looks like `rosrun rosserial_mbed make_libraries.py <ros-lib-dir>` creates header files for board and only MbedHardware.h directly related with mbed.

I'm not an expert on microcontroller, so I am just wondering can I simply use rosserials make_library.py command and use generated ros message headers on my code?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/255283/can-i-use-rosserial-mbed-library-without-using-mbed-os?/) by [ozgurerbulan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28712/ozgurerbulan/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-02-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-02-22**:
If you don't plan to use mbed, could you not use any of the other targets that `rosserial` supports?

**Comment by [ozgurerbulan](https://answers.ros.org/users/28712/ozgurerbulan/) on 2017-02-22**:
I just realise that I do not needrosserial_mbed, `rosrun rosserial_clint make_libraries.py`  does the same job. So can I use that libraries with ARM cmsis RTOS or freeRTOS?

**Comment by [chrisalbertson](https://answers.ros.org/users/21344/chrisalbertson/) on 2018-06-14**:
mbed is actually the ARM cmsis RTOS.  That is what is inside.  If you need better performance use the command line compiler.There you can set the target for "deploy" and it removes the debug code and allows optimizations that would make debugging hard,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, you only have to add a class for your hardware that implement the methods `read()`, `write()` and `time()`, then include it and call the constructor in the `ros.h` file.

You can use some implementations as examples:

- [rosserial_mbed](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/jade-devel/rosserial_mbed/src/ros_lib/MbedHardware.h)
- [rosserial_arduino](https://github.com/ros-drivers/rosserial/blob/jade-devel/rosserial_arduino/src/ros_lib/ArduinoHardware.h)
- [rosserial_chibios](https://github.com/SyrianSpock/stm32f4discovery_rosserial/blob/master/src/ros_lib/ChibiOSHardware.h)

---

Originally posted by [rreignier](https://answers.ros.org/users/21983/rreignier/) with karma: 544 on 2017-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0